# codeigniter select join twice from same table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have 3 tables, where is the first one for user. In another two I have id_user, for product who created or activation who created. How I can show all data from these two tables with both username? I figure out how to join 2 tables, but third I have join twice and I don't know how. This is example for two tables:

```
        $query=$this->db->select('*')
                ->from('activation')
                ->join('products','products.id_pro = activation.id_pro')
                ->order_by('id_key','DESC')
                ->get();
```

Table activation has column user_a with user id, and product has column user_p with user id. Sometimes is same user sometimes not. Any helps?

Answer (score 3):

Heres how I do it using aliases. You can format it your way too.

```
 $this->db->select('tb1.*,tb2.*,u.*');
 $this->db->join('table1name tb1','tb1.id = u.tb1_id');
 $this->db->join('table2name tb2','tb2.id = u.tb2_id');
 $this->db->order_by('u.id_key','DESC');
 $result = $this->db->get('User u')->result();
```

If you want to alter between left and right join just add 'left' or 'right' to the join function.

```
 $this->db->join('table1name pr1','pr1.id = u.tb1_id','right');
 $this->db->join('table2name tb2','tb2.id = u.tb2_id','right');
```

This would preference your user table.

Comment: I don't understand. Imagine  that I have for instance 3 table. First is product, second is activation and third is user. How do make query where I will get one row with join all 3 tables, but username from user table to call twice (sometimes is same sometimes isn't)?

Comment: sorry i did understant the ' but username from user table to call twice (sometimes is same sometimes isn't' part.  And the above query will return and array of rows with all columns from table one,two, and three.  If you want the result to be just the last row, you could use ``->row()`` instead of ``->result()``.