# I need to compare two different columns in different rows using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**I need to compare two columns l_area and d_area in different rows .**

Need to output consignment table results if l_area in row 1 is equal to d_area in row 2

Below is my model, but its checking the same row

```
public function return_loads()  
{  
    $where='d_area=l_area';
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('consignment');          
    $this->db->where('consignment.status',0); 
    $this->db->where($where);    
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show what query is generated by printing query?

Comment: and why not use $where='d_area=l_area AND consignment.status=0';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a join here:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM consignement c
INNER JOIN consignement c2
  ON c.d_area = c2.d_area
WHERE c.consignement_status=0
-- AND c2.consignement_status=0
```

not sure about the last part of where clause, it depends on your specific use case. This is raw SQL, but you could use codeIngiter's `join()` for that:

```
public function return_loads()  
{  
    $where='d_area=l_area';
    $this->db->select('c1.*');
    $this->db->from('consignment c1');
    $this->db->join('consignement c2', 'c1.l_area = c2.d_area', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('c1.status',0); 
    $this->db->where($where);    -- use 'c1' instead of 'consignement' in your where clause
    $query = $this->db->get();      
    return $query;
 }
```

you can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042341/codeigniter-select-join-twice-from-same-table).